# Automatically choose proportional time for time_bucket(), depends on selected time window of query and expected quantity of points

Tags: sql, timescaledb

I use timescaleDB especial time_bucket() method in this kinds of queries.

```
SELECT time_bucket('**1 day**', time) AS datetime, temp.inside_t FROM temp where serial in ('77777777777', '77777777778')   and time > '2020-**02-03** 13:54:46.768000'  and time < '2020-**03-04** 13:53:46.768000'  GROUP BY datetime   ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT time_bucket('**1 hour**', time) AS datetime, temp.inside_t FROM temp where serial in ('77777777777', '77777777778')   and time > '2020-**03-03** 13:54:46.768000'  and time < '2020-**03-04** 13:53:46.768000' GROUP BY datetime   ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Depends of time window of query and quantity of expected points, I should **manually** calculate the appropriate time period ( **1 day**, or **6 hour**, of **15 minutes**)

In my case, is`t possible just measure time window of query and just send expected quantity of points, for instance i want to receive **100 points**.

```
SELECT time_bucket(**100**) AS datetime, temp.inside_t FROM temp where serial in ('77777777777', '77777777778')   and time > '2020-02-03 13:54:46.768000'  and time < '2020-03-04 13:53:46.768000' GROUP BY datetime   ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Or some appropriate **alternative** for time_bucket().

I read this [article](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/simplified-time-series-analytics-using-the-time_bucket-function/) but fined nothing interesting.

**Update**
what API handle this request
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution came from looking at how to work Grafana.  Must be subtracted from by and divided by the number of desired points, so determine the number of seconds by which you can get the desired number of points.

```
    List get(long from, long until, long maxDataPoints) {
    final String query = String.format("SELECT time_bucket('%s seconds', time) AS dateTime, avg(temp.inside), avg(temp.outside) FROM temp where serial in ('777777777') and time > '2020-03-03 13:54:46.768000' and time < '2020-03-04 13:54:46.768000' GROUP BY dateTime ORDER BY dateTime DESC;",
        round((until - from) / maxDataPoints));
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper());
```

BTW here is another useful [method](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#interpolate-examples).